# Animating the size of markers in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, networkx, scatter

I am animating a network graph, and would like to show node-related data via the size of the nodes.  An equivalent animation for color rather than node size by:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

G = nx.ladder_graph(4)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nc = np.random.random(len(G))
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_color=nc)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)

def update(n):
  nc = np.random.random(len(G))
  nodes.set_array(nc)
  return nodes,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=20, blit=True)
```

And one static frame with the node size given by the data can be generated with

```
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=400*nc)
```

I understand that there isn't an equivalent of .set_array for the size characteristic, so what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is the `self._size` attribute.  In new versions of mpl (1.4.0rc1 + ) there is a
`set_sizes` method on `PathCollection`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.  Is documentation available for matplotlib 1.4?

Comment: It isn't posted online yet, but you can build it from source